# Conditional subexpression replacement using regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, replace, raku

I have text input similar to that shown below. I'd like to add the word `auto` before each 'a=b' pattern, but only if it is part of a sequence following the keyword `kywrd` (separated by semicolons).

```
kywrd a=b;c=d;
e=f;
fnctn z;
g=h;
```

So the output I'm looking for here is:

```
kywrd2 auto a=b;auto c=d;
auto e=f;
fnctn z;
g=h;
```

The Perl6 (Raku?) code below uses a regular expression to add the `auto` keyword, but only before the *first* `a=b` pattern. Is there a simple way to perform the substitution for all patterns in the sequence; leaving `g=h;` unmodified?

```perl
my Str $x = slurp "in.q";
$x ~~ s:g /kywrd\s+(\w+)\=(\w+)\;/kywrd2 auto $0=$1\;/;
spurt "out.q", $x;
```

Comment: Do you want a solution for perl5 or perl6?

Comment: The `Str`, the `s:g`, the `$0` and the `spurt` give away that a Raku solution is wanted, I think.  :-)

Comment: I'm new to both perls, but slightly drawn to perl6.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way that keeps the regexing to a minimum:

```
sub repl ($input) 
{ 
    $input.Str
    .split(';', :skip-empty)
    .map( 'auto ' ~ * ~ ';')
    .join('')
 };

 my $foo = 'kywrd a=b;c=d;d=e;'; 
 $foo ~~ s:g /kywrd \s+ (.+)/kywrds2 { repl($0) }/; 
 $foo.say;
```

Personally I'd prefer the method form `subst` over the `s//` operator though.

```
$foo .= subst(/ kywrd \s+ (.+) /, "kywrds2 { repl($0) }", :g);
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you prefer the method form?

Comment: Methods can be chained. Also the method form makes it more clear the replacement is "just a string".

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
# Create a separate named regex that captures an `x=y;` pair:
my regex pair { (\w+) \= (\w+) \; (\s*) }
# (Capture `(\s*)` so formatting between pairs is retained)

# Generate and return 'auto'-ized replacement of a captured pair: 
sub auto-ize ($/) { "auto $0=$1;$2" }

$x ~~ s:g { kywrd \s+ <pair>+ } = "kywrd2 $<pair>».&auto-ize.join()";
```

All the code I've shown would be simple to understand for someone a little familiar with Raku but I'll explain it anyway.

- I've broken out a named regex to match a pair. (See [my answer to **Difference in capturing and non-capturing regex scope in Perl 6 / Raku**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158918/1077672) for details about why/how `<pair>` calls the `pair` regex.)
- The `auto-ize` sub routine uses [the match variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-match_variable) (`$/`) as its argument. This is convenient because `$0` etc. are then automatically aliased to the numbered captures associated with the passed match object.
- I've used syntax of the form `s [ ... ] = " ... "` because I think it's more readable for this use case. (See mention of "different delimiters" in [`s///` doc](https://docs.perl6.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS).)
- The "kywrd2 ..." string will be repeatedly evaluated and become a replacement of a match, once for each match of the multiple `s:g` matches.
- The `$<pair>».&auto-ize.join()` bit is code being [interpolated](https://docs.perl6.org/language/101-basics#index-entry-interpolation) under double quoted string rules.
- `$<pair>` is short for `$/<pair>`, i.e. the `<pair>` key of `$/`. It refers to the `pair` named capture associated with [the match variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-match_variable). The latter will correspond to each match of the multiple `s:g` matches in turn.
- The `+` quantifier in the regex expression `<pair>+` means that, if it matches, it produces a *`List`* of capture (match) objects rather than just one (as would be the case if the expression was instead just `<pair>` or `<pair>?`).
- [`»`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators) treats its LHS operand as a tree or list (in this case a list of one or more capture/match objects, one per `foo=bar;...` pair) and walks over its elements. For each "leaf" element the `»` does the operation on its right. (`»` is a powerful operator but has nice simple use cases such as this one where it's just a notationally convenient and compact equivalent of a `for` loop. You can write it as `>>` if you prefer ASCII.)
- `.&auto-ize` calls the `auto-ize` sub routine as if it were a method, using the operand to its left as the first argument.

The test input data from @PolarBear's answer:

```
kywrd a=b;c=d;
e=f;
fnctn z;
g=h;
k=m;
fnctn y;
kywrd m=n;
k=j;
kywrd z=a;b=i;
kywrd c=x;e=i;
z=q;
fnctn o;
```

Putting that into `in.q` and `say`ing the resulting `out.q` displays:

```
kywrd2 auto a=b;auto c=d;
auto e=f;
fnctn z;
g=h;
k=m;
fnctn y;
kywrd2 auto m=n;
auto k=j;
kywrd2 auto z=a;auto b=i;
kywrd2 auto c=x;auto e=i;
auto z=q;
fnctn o;
```

Answer (score 3):

Not very elegant but workable code (ancient way)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

OUTER: while(<DATA>) {
    if( s/kywrd /kywrd2 / ) {
        do {
            if( ! s/(\w+)=(\w+)/auto $1=$2/g ) {
                print;
                next OUTER;
            }
            print;
        } while ( <DATA> );
    } else {
        print;
    }
}

__DATA__
kywrd a=b;c=d;
e=f;
fnctn z;
g=h;
k=m;
fnctn y;
kywrd m=n;
k=j;
kywrd z=a;b=i;
kywrd c=x;e=i;
z=q;
fnctn o;
```

I need to look at Raku - what kind of *animal* it is.