# Combining state and token throws. Why?

Tags: regex, raku

This works

```
sub test-string( $string )
{
    my token opening-brace { \( };
    my token closing-brace { \) };
    my token balanced-braces { 
        ( <opening-brace>+ ) <closing-brace> ** { $0.chars } 
    };

    so $string ~~ /^ <balanced-braces> $/;
}
```

This

```
sub test-string( $string )
{
    state token opening-brace { \( };
    state token closing-brace { \) };
    state token balanced-braces { 
        ( <opening-brace>+ ) <closing-brace> ** { $0.chars } 
    };

    so $string ~~ /^ <balanced-braces> $/;
}
```

dies with

```
No such method 'opening-brace' for invocant of type 'Match'
  in regex balanced-braces at ch-2.p6 line 13
  in sub test-string at ch-2.p6 line 17
  in block <unit> at ch-2.p6 line 23
```

I would prefer the second version, since I believe the first version is quite inefficient when it has to set up the `token`s every time the function is called. So if this were real code and not a challenge entry, I'd have to make the tokens (file) global.

Why does this even happen?

Comment: Can you declare a grammar inside your function? I'm pretty sure that will act much like a state var.

Comment: Matching delimiters can be coded directly https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Tilde_for_nesting_structures Is there some reason you are not using that? Also, tokens are just functions, and they are not going to keep state from one call to the next. I don't really see the point of using state here. Additionally, a grammar would be a better option for this, as @ScimonProctor says

Comment: @jjmerelo "functions ... are not going to keep state from one call to the next"  But that's precisely one of the use cases for a `state` declarator -- `sub foo { state $foo++; state $bar--; $foo, $bar }; foo; say foo;` displays `(2 -2)`. It's just that `state` isn't working for a routine *declaration* (as questioned by Holli and explored a little in my answer). That's not the same as wanting `state` for a routine *call*. (That all said, I agree that a grammar is likely the best option. I would guess it'll be both nicer and perform better than any of the takes in my answer.)

Comment: @raiph I should have been clearer here. Tokens are functions, and those are the functions I mean were not going to keep state. It's the same as if you declare a sub or method as a state. There's no way they will keep a state from one call to the next.

Comment: @jmerelo "Tokens are functions" I know that. I know `say token {.}.^mro` by heart. You didn't need to be clearer. "[a sub won't] keep a state from one call to the next." Can't you see the problem with your wording? How do *you* explain the result `(2 -2)` rather than `(1 -1)` in my prior comment? "There's no way". One of the more radical things about Raku is that it's built atop [scoped continuations](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scoped+continuations%22), so there is even a way to retain callframes. That's how a dynamic cross-call `gather`/`take` works.

Comment: @jjmerelo Despite the foregoing, I agree that use of `state` to declare a routine is akin to a mirage because routine declaration declares a constant anyway. That's why I wrote **take 2** in my answer. I wanted to guide Holli to either prove to themselves and us, with precision, what issue they need fixed in an actual use case, or realize things are already reasonably optimal as is. I fully expect them to conclude the latter but I placed take 2 *after* take 1 because I didn't want to *start* with a cluebat and it's always possible I have misunderstood what they're saying or how things work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** I like [take **0**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615980/combining-state-and-token-throws-why?noredirect=1#comment105395547_59615980). There's a workaround (see take **1**) but I don't think it's worthwhile. I don't think it's inefficient with a plain `my` (see take **2**). I think use of `state` with a regex/method should be rejected at compile time (see takes **3** and **5**) or left as is (see take **4**). Unless you're a coding genius willing to persuade jnthn that Rakudo should embark on a dramatic increased exposure to continuations (see take **5**).

## Why does this even happen? (take 1)

"This" doesn't if you write like so:

```
sub test-string( $string )
{
    state &opening-brace = token { \( }
    state &closing-brace = token { \) }
    state &balanced-braces = token { 
        ( <&opening-brace>+ ) <&closing-brace> ** { $0.chars } 
    }

    so $string ~~ /^ <&balanced-braces> $/;
}
```

(The need for the `&` in the regex calls slightly surprises me.<sup>1</sup>)

## Why does this even happen? (take 2)

Why does *what* happen?

> I believe the first version is quite inefficient when it has to set up the tokens every time the function is called.

What do you mean by "believe" and "quite inefficient" and "set up the tokens"? I would *expect* the regex code to be compiled just once (I'd be shocked if it were compiled each time) but haven't profiled to verify.

Which leads me to a series of questions:

Is your concern purely the time taken to recreate the 3 lexpad entries (`&opening-parens` etc.; more generally, number of regexes) each time the `test-string` function is called?

Have you actually profiled running your original code and seen a significant problem?

Have you truly measured this and found it to be [part of your "critical 3%"](https://docs.raku.org/language/performance) in an actual project?

## Why does this even happen? (take 3)

The `state` declarator does a reasonable thing with `sub`s -- it produces a compile-time error:

```
state sub foo {}    # Compile time error: "Cannot use 'state' with sub declaration"
state my sub foo {} # Compile time error: "Type 'my' is not declared"
```

But with a method (which is what a regex is under the covers) it compiles but does nothing useful:

```
state method foo {} # Compiles, but I failed to find a way to access `foo`
state regex bar {.}  # Same
```

I've looked in Rakudo's GH issues queue and failed to find an issue discussing anything like the last two lines of code above (which are essentially the same as your `token` case). Perhaps folk haven't noticed this or at least didn't feel it would be helpful to file a bug?

## Why does this even happen? (take 4)

So you would post an SO documenting that `state regex` should be rejected at compile-time or do something useful. And @Scimon++ would document another way to look at things. And me some more.

## Why does this even happen? (take 5)

```
<Your Compiler Code Goes Here>
```

Because [Raku is our MMORPG](http://strangelyconsistent.org/blog/perl-6-is-my-mmorpg). If you would prefer to see the `state` declarator do something useful when used with a routine declaration (presumably it should either produce a compile-time error, like it currently does with a `sub`, or do some fancy continuation thing within the constraint of the ["scoped continuations"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scoped+continuations%22) atop which Raku is built), then  that work is plausibly just a "smop" away given that the Rakudo compiler is mostly written in Raku. Someone has deliberately made `state` on a `sub` a compile-time error, and the continuation notion would be a truly colossal project, so I think the appropriate thing, if any, in the next few years, would be to make `state` on a method or rule also a compile-time error.

Or, perhaps more appropriately still, now this is covered by an SO, with a documented alternative (a grammar) and workaround (take 1), it's just time to move on to the next level...

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> See [my answer to **Difference in ... regex scope**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158918/1077672). The behavior of the regexes declared with `state` appear not to be following a straight-forward reading of the design speculation I quoted in that answer. And at least the following bit of my narrative from that answer is wrong too...

> "`<bar>` is as explained above. It preferentially resolves to an early bound lexical (`my`/`our`) routine/rule named `&bar`.

...because in the take 1 code of this answer the regex calls have to be prefixed with an `&` to work. Maybe it's pure accident they work at all.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. I still suffer from Perlisms at times. Tokens are functions, gotcha. I also agree the error message could be better.

Comment: It was slightly interesting to ponder `state sub` declaring a continuation. What would it even mean? The only things I've thought of so far end up as either synchronous, which is already covered by dynamic `gather`/`take`, or asynchronous, which is already covered by `await`. In retrospect, given what you've written, the answer should basically be "regexes aren't strings in Raku" and perhaps @jmerelo should write that and you should switch to accepting that answer. In the meantime, thank you for the polite euphemism "elaborate". :)

Comment: "I failed to find a way to access `foo`" -- `(state method foo { say 42 })(0)`, although maybe thats not quite what you meant.

Comment: @ugexe Yes, on both counts. (I had tried `state method { say self }(42)` to convince myself that it code-gen'd *something* half reasonable. I had presumed it would work if I inserted a name but didn't try because I was, as you surmised might be the case, only interested in accessing the method in a separate statement from its declaration via its name. Thanks for clarifying for other readers.)